# Errors on Celery Daemon Startup

Tags: ubuntu, celery, systemd, django-celery, celeryd

I need to setup celery on production so I'am daemonizing celery in a Ubuntu machine. I'm getting errors on service startup but I cannot figure out how to solve them.

Here is my `/etc/default/celeryd` file:

```
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"

CELERY_BIN="/home/jim/.virtualenv/bin/celery"

CELERY_APP="mysite"

CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/jim/mysite/"

CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the node name.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/beat.log"

CELERYD_USER="jim"
CELERYD_GROUP="jim"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

And here is my `/etc/systemd/system/celery.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=jim
Group=jim
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/celeryd
WorkingDirectory=/home/jim/mysite
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now if I run these two commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start celery.service
```

I get this output on service startup:

> Job for celery.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status celery.service" and "journalctl -xe"
> for details.

`sudo systemctl status celery.service` outputs this, which doesn't give me much information about the specific issue, (maybe I'm missing something):

```
● celery.service - Celery Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-07-21 14:17:57 UTC; 1min 18s ago
  Process: 18279 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c ${CELERY_BIN} -A ${CELERY_APP} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 Main PID: 23362 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 21 14:17:56 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 21 14:17:56 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 21 14:17:56 domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Celery Service.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped Celery Service.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: celery.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 21 14:17:57 domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Celery Service.
```

However, running `journalctl -xe` shows this error log:

```
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com systemd[18367]: celery.service: Executing: /bin/sh -c '/home/jim/.virtualenv/bin/celery -A mysite multi start worker1 --pidfile=/var/run/celery/%n.pid --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log --loglevel=INFO --time-limit=300 --concurrency=8'
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     sys.exit(main())
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     sys.exit(_main())
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in main
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     _verify_python3_env()
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:   File "/home/jim/.virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 130, in _verify_python3_env
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     " mitigation steps.{}".format(extra)
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]: RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Consult https://click.palletsproject
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]: This system supports the C.UTF-8 locale which is recommended. You might be able to resolve your issue by exporting the following environment variables:
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
Jul 21 14:21:30 domain.com sh[18367]:     export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I need to clarify that even exporting those two variables `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` and `LANG=C.UTF-8` in the enviroment dosen't fix the issue, and I keep getting the same error message. I have already tried to run the service start command manually and works fine and the celery worker is initiated, any ideas on what am I doing wrong? I have searched for similar issues on daemonizing celery but I haven't found anything so far.